# При конкантенации строк в SQL выводит 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Запрос вида "SELECT imya+familiya ....  " Выводит в ячейку 0, оба поля varchar, как это сделать правильно? MySQL,phpmyadmin,InnoDB

Comment: В MySQL + складывает числа и строки приводит к числам. конкатенация выполняется исключительно функцией `concat()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже ответили выше, используйте функцию [`concat`](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html):

```
SELECT concat(imya, ' ', familiya) as fio from table
```